# Image File Won't Display

Tags: html, css

When I try to upload an image file form my computer in my html file it doesn't show up in browser. But if I link a image file from the web it works. I've copied the file path correctly and made sure the extensions were correct. Is it something wrong with the file itself?[Code In Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huDEB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the picture you've attached you're placing an *absolute* filepath inside `src` while it should be *relative*, considering the file might be in the same folder as the HTML, but not in the same user folder/operating system etc.

To fix your issue I have an example below.

**Folder layout:**

- website

  - index.html
  - images

    - myimage.jpg

**Referencing:**

How to reference to `myimage.jpg` relatively is by putting `images/myimage.jpg` inside the `src` attribute. The way you're doing it is `website/images/myimage.jpg`, but another user might not have the website in a folder called `website` but `website2` for example.

Comment: No problem! Could you mark it as solved if it solved your issue? :)